# Getting child elements that are related to a parent in same table

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have the following database schema

```
class posts(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'xposts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 



class Comments(Base):  
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 
    comment_parent_id=Column(Integer,unique=True)  
    #comment_id fetches comment of a comment ie the comment_parent_id
    comment_id=Column(Integer,default=None)
    comment_text=Column(String(200))
```

Values in database are

```
1   12  NULL    Hello First comment
2   NULL    12  First Sub comment
```

I want to fetch all Comments and sub comments of a post using sqlalchemy and have this so far

```
qry=session.query(Comments).filter(Comments.comment_parent_id!=None)
print qry.count()
```

Is there a way i can fetch the all the subcomments of a comment in a query i have tried outerjoin on the same table(comments) and it seemed stupid and it failed.

Comment: here's a good example in sqlalchemy's documentation for self referential foreignkey's: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#adjacency-list-relationships

Comment: Can i get an outerjoin example because a join won't work as a comment may lack subcomments?

Answer (score 1):

you used the all() function in sqlalchemy query after that you can used count and len for find the total row in database.
because this query provide the 2'd list result.

```
qry=session.query(Comments).filter(Comments.comment_parent_id!=None).all()

len(qry)
```

Comment: The len(qry) part is insignificant as of now, i was just testing if there were results being returned.